# Setting up an integral in terms of x-axis

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to setup an integral to find the area of the surface of revolution of this function about the x-axis, but I am not sure of the steps to take .

$x = y + y^3$, $0 \leq y \leq 1$

I am not sure what steps to take to get the bounds for $x$ and to set the function up properly.

**Bounds:** Is it as simple as plugging in $0,1$ into y and solving for x such that $x = 0 + 0 = 0$ and $x = 1 + 1 = 2$?

**Solving for y and dy:**
$$y = x - y^3$$

$$\begin{align}
x &= y + y^3 \\
dx &= dy(1 + 3y^2) \\
\frac{dx}{(1+3y^2)} &= dy \\
\frac{1}{(1+3y^2)} &= \frac{dy}{dx}
\end{align}$$

That leaves me with 
$$S = \int 2\pi y \sqrt{1+\bigg[ \frac{dy}{dx} \bigg]^2}dx \\
= \int_{0}^{2} 2\pi (x - y^3) \sqrt{1+\bigg[ \frac{1}{(1+3y^2)} \bigg]^2}dx$$

I feel that this integral isn't set up properly and that there shouldn't be a $y^3$ in the integral when integrating in relation to $x$.

Comment: Have you thought to integrate in terms of $y$? Because you could replace $dx$ with $(1+3y^2)dy$ which will leave you with

$$S=\int_0^1 2\pi y \sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{(1+3y^2)^2}}(1+3y^2)dy$$

Comment: I thought $y$ in this instance meant $f(y)$. Why are you allowed to use $y$ vs $f(y)$ in some instances? I don't understand the use cases.

Comment: I'm doing everything that you have done before your last line, except I am converting between $dx$ and $dy$, which you have generated a relationship between. The equality still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that if you use the already given parametric form of the rotated curve

- $(x(t),y(t)) = (t+t^3,t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$

you get immediately for rotation about the $x$-axis
$$2\pi\int_0^1y(t)\sqrt{\dot x(t)^2 + \dot y(t)^2}\; dt = 2\pi\int_0^1 t\sqrt{(1+3t)^2 + 1}\; dt$$

Comment: I've looked more into parametric forms...what makes you say that the parametric form is already given for a rotated curve? Does this imply that all rotated curves have either $x(t) = t$ or $y(t) = t$ as part of the parametric form?

Comment: In your example the curve is given in the form of $x = x(y)$. So, this is a special case, where you can consider $y=t$ as the parameter. Other curves might be given in the form $y=y(x)$. Then you can see $x=t$ as the parameter. A different example would be $(x(t),y(t)) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ for $t \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, where you do not have immediately one of the coordinates as a parameter.

Comment: To turn $x = y + y^3$ into parametric form, all you have to do is simply have $x,y = t$? Then $x = t = x$ (identity of itself) and $ x = t + t^3$?

Comment: Surely you mean $y=t$. So,  "it is itself". This means, with $t=y$, your integral could also be written as
$$2\pi\int_0^1y(t)\sqrt{\dot x(t)^2 + \dot y(t)^2}\; dt = 2\pi\int_0^1 y\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2 + 1}\; dy$$ That way you can see that the parametric form of the integral using $(x(t),y(t))$ is more general and contains the cases where curves are given in the form $x= x(y)$ or $y=y(x)$ as special cases. $x= x(y)$ corresponds to $y=t$ and $y=y(x)$ corresponds to $x=t$.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate in terms of $y$ by using the transformation between $dx$ and $dy$.

$$\begin{align}
S&=\int_0^1 2\pi y \sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{(1+3y^2)^2}}(1+3y^2)dy
\\
S&=\int_0^1 2\pi y \sqrt{(1+3y^2)^2+1}dy
\end{align}$$

Let $u=1+3y^2$ such that $du=6ydy$ and by substitution

$$\begin{align}
S&=\dfrac{\pi}{3}\int_1^4 \sqrt{u^2+1}du
\end{align}$$

Comment: Integrating in terms of $y$ such that $S = \int 2\pi y$ means that $y$ represents the radius of the circular slab and since we are looking for the surface area, we want to find the circumference. In the integral, $y$ is the y value that you get in $ x = y + y^3$.

Since $y$ is an arbitrary value, that is why we can use the term $y$ rather than having to use $f(x) = y + y^3$ in the integral?

Comment: @EvanKim As has been mentioned, this can be seen as a parametric form. I know that you mentioned you are not familiar with them. The point is, I took your equation that is measuring area and I made equal substitutions. By changing the limits of integration, I am still measuring the same result. What I am doing is essentially the same as a $u$ substitution, except I don't have to consider what $u$ is. It is given to me as a "coordinate transformation" if you will.

Comment: hmm okay. I will familiarize myself more with parametric form then